# custom schema in native query with jpa repository

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i want to use custom schema in interface jpa repository with native query like this :

application.yaml :

```
schema:
 name:
  first: schema1
  second: schema2
```

Jpa Repository :

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,String> {

 @Query(value = "SELECT ID FROM ${schema.name.first1}.users WHERE NUMERO  = " +
                "(SELECT EMPLOYEE_NUMBER FROM ${schema.name.first2}.employees WHERE ID = :lastModifiedByID)"
String getUserCreationByID(@Param("id") String id);
.....
}
```

but when I run the application with SQL trace, the parameter ${schema.name.first1} does not get the value from application.yaml and uses it as query and exits with SQL error

trace :

```
Hibernate: SELECT ID FROM ${schema.name.first1}.users WHERE NUMERO (SELECT EMPLOYEE_NUMBER FROM ${schema.name.first2}.employees WHERE ID = ?)
 SQL Error: 17034, SQLState: 99999
```

Thanks

has anyone used a custom schema with a native query?